# Angular PUT send option and that's it nothing else

Tags: angular, http, cors, put

So I have an Angular app with different call to a REST api to GET,POST work as intended they don't send any option preflight nothing but when it comes to put it's just hell, I couldn't find answer on google and I have tried every single header. At this point I just think PUT is not a real request... I'm really desperate.

This is how i'm making my calls in my angular app:

```
    Connect = function(){
    console.log("dbConnect");
    let options = new RequestOptions({ withCredentials: true });
    this._http.get('http://localhost:443/some/Connect', options)
        .subscribe();
}

Read = function(){
    console.log("Read");
    let options = new RequestOptions({ withCredentials: true });
    this._http.post('http://localhost:443/some/Read','', options)
        .subscribe(); 
}

Create = function(){
    console.log("Create");
    let data = '{...}';
    this._http.put('http://localhost:443/some/Create',data) 
        .subscribe(); <- only sends option
}
```

I've set every single header i could on my server.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT 
    Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

I've tried different headers on the actual request like:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
headers.append("Authorization",btoa("user:pass"));
```

What ever i try it just sends OPTION and that's all. Why it doesn't do it for POST and GET then? I really have no idea i've spent way too much time on this, there's really no clear explanation i have found on google on how to make this work. I understand there must be a preflight but then even if i answer with what ever header you want it doesn't do anything more... And i can see when i press F12 that the headers i answered with are there in the response but angular just doesn't care at all.

Any ideas how i can make my PUT work?

This is cors i communicate localhost to localhost (different ports). I tried using a plugin "cors everywhere" on firefox but and disabling that plugin will still work cause i allow my client side port on my server side. Everything work with and without corse only that PUT method doesn't work.. please help

## EDIT for the answer

If you have the same problem: For me what solved it was to not set a realm on server side if the request is OPTION.

Comment: Thats how preflight requests works in all browsers, you can not (and should not) do anything about it. If your request stuck on OPTION phase, then you probably got an error in console. Try posting it too.

Comment: @VagrantAI "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:443/some/Create. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed)." preflight did not succeed.

Comment: That means that your endpoint http://localhost:443/DYNAMIC_CLASSE/CreateDTO is not configured the proper way. It may use wrong CORS politics, that is your backend problem actually and not angular.

Comment: @VagrantAI My server side requires user and login if the request doesn't send (since it's option it doesn't send nothing) i set a realm. That's all. I also use SoapUI to test and not only angular. From soap UI the request with POST PUT and GET all work with no problem. That's not a server side problem.

Comment: Your server rejects your PUT, not Angular. That means that some of the filters (CORS or authorization, I dont know) on server side are not being applied to current PUT request. Seems like you implemented your authorization filter the hard way, checking all type of requests, which you should not do.

Comment: @VagrantAI How is it possible that a PUT from SoapUI works but from angular doesn't? I don't aim soapUI or Angular, i treat both the same way. If that wouldn't work with soap ui then i would question my server side but if it work on SoapUI and Jmeter it must be angular not doing something.

Comment: because it does not send preflight requests?

Comment: @VagrantAI omg you solved it. I don't have to set a realm when it's option and just answet with the headers then i get the put. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case I was using node server. Adding the plugins will help as well but that's not the real way, I guess.

I added the following lines to my server code:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
```

Comment: Tried, doesn't work. I can see the headers are there in the response but agular just stops after option and doesn't do anything more.

Comment: btw which version are you using ? which server ?

Comment: Angular 4. My server is coded in delphi. It's a rest application that i test with SoapUI and Jmeter. (which work no matter the type of the request) Only angular doen't work with PUT.

Comment: just use http instead of using it like _http

Comment: that wasn't it. I just had to not set a realm when it's a preflight then i get the put on my server side.